# Callback URL no funciona en firebase

Tags: nodejs, express, passport

Resulta que estoy implementado un login en un proyecto con auth0, y el tema es que en local todo funciona de maravilla, pero una vez que ya hice el deploy del proyecto en firebase, e intento hacer login en el sitio, este me arroja el siguiente error 404: Cannot GET /auth/callback.
Un dato relevante en todo esto es que tengo bien configurada mi app en auth0, tal como lo muestro en la imagen de referencia. La configuración de mi passport-auth0 es la siguiente:

```
passport.use(new Auth0Strategy({domain:process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
                                  clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,     
                                  clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
                                  callbackURL: 'https://mi-firebase-app.web.app/auth/callback' },
```

Y la configuración de la ruta es esta:

```
router.get('https://mi-firebase-app.web.app/auth/callback', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('auth0', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
        req.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            res.redirect('/profile');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

[image: Allowed Callback URLs]

Comment: y que tienes en `https://mi-firebase-app.web.app/auth/callback`?

Comment: Es el segundo código que se muestra arriba, la configuración de la ruta

Comment: UPDATE: Logré solucionar el problema de 404. Tuve que cambiar configuración de la ruta de callback. Solo cambié la url https://mi-firebase-app.web.app/auth/callback por /auth/callback y return res.redirect('/login'); por return res.redirect('/registro');

Comment: Pero ahora tengo otro problema, y es que cuando mi app está siendo hosteada por firebase, la autenticación no se está haciendo, por ende en la ruta de callback se ejecuta la siguiente linea de código if (!user) { return res.redirect('/registro'); }